# Jmeter GUI suddenly froze in the middle of a test run

Tags: java, user-interface, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a test on jmeter (200 threads; 3000 ramp up period) and in the middle of the test the jmeter gui suddenly froze (the test is still running).

I just want to know if there is any possibility that I could still get the summary result of the finished test run on jmeter considering the fact that the gui froze and I could not get the summary results in it?

Comment: GUI got freeze because of the heavy operations being performed by 200 threads and all the resources such as Memory, CPU are already occupied. it is because lack of the system resources (most probably CPU or memory of the machine)

Answer (score 1):

It is: **don't use JMeter GUI for load test execution**, GUI mode is for test development and debugging. Once you are happy with your test behaviour:

1. Disable all the listeners
2. Tweak JVM settings (at least increase Java heap space)
3. [Run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
   ```
4. When test finishes you will be able to:

   - Using JMeter GUI open `results.jtl` file using the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice
   - [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) like:

     ```
     jmeter -g /path/to/results.jtl -o /path/to/html/report/folder
     ```

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for compilation of JMeter performance tuning advices.